# Using scala to access google API, front end in Ruby on Rails

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, scala, google-api-java-client

So my main application is written in Ruby/Rails and that is where the preliminary oauth2 action is happening. Currently I store the email and refresh token from that initial interaction, and now want to use a Scala script to retrieve data from the api in the background using the users credentials. (the point of an API  no..?)

After following many examples from the google java api client example page:https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples, I have found that they want me to re-authenticate users via opening a new tab and physically log in. Because I've already authenticated them, is there a way for me to simply continually retrieve data without requiring them to log in again, as this script should be running in the background?

Comment: If you have an access/refresh token and the user hasn't revoked access then you shouldn't need to re-authenticate them upon subsequent requests, unless you set `approval_prompt` to `force` in your initial request for the token. What errors are you seeing specifically from google?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the flow is to even get a new access token for a specific user. 

I have my own client_id, client_secret, and their refresh_token. In scala I'm using the java-api-client library, and I can't find any examples thus far that allow me to use this information to access the API

As you can see here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java

it seems that the only way to access an API is to create a credential, and creating a credential automatically requires me to open up a new tab and authenticate again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To refresh an access token using the `java-api-client` library:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential

val credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(transport)
.setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
.setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
.build()

credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken) // get token from DB or wherever you have persisted it
credential.refreshToken()
credential.getAccessToken // returns new, refreshed access token
```

Comment: Thank you so much! (Sorry I also didn't realize that I was a "server to server" or service client), which also made everything that much more complicated, but this fixed everything!